# I want to add the docusign API with my web application software

Tags: docusignapi

I want to add the docusign API with my application I create the docusign development account. I dont want  to go mail to the signer. Its work automatically when my a user enter in my website and click to button go to docosign application. How i can do that. any one can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Marco is right that you need to be careful about how you authenticate users who are coming into your application.  The proof that the signature took place is only as strong as your authentication system.  DocuSign has over 7 security options and the e-mail activation gives it more validity.

Having said all that you can absolutely embed DocuSign into your application.  Here is a walkthrough on how you can embed DocuSign into your web application: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/embedded-signing

Comment: The embedded signing was not so flexible last time I integrated DocuSign in an app. Good to know. Nevertheless, I am sure that if you use this approach it will be harder to get your integration certified by DocuSign: you will need to demonstrate that your authentication mechanism is 100% secure. At the end, they add your authentication in the Certificate of completion. If it is not good enough, it will be hard to demonstrate that the signatory actually signed the contract.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a link in your application because this would reduce the value of the electronic signature: it would be more difficult to proof that the real signatory signed the document if the link was accessible not only to the recipient of the email.

DocuSign wants to be sure that their servers are the only one who manage the links for signatories.

There is no API to get the link.

Comment: no the user who signing the documents is already authenticated by us.

Comment: I wants the user who login in the application and then login the in docusign get his username and password and intregator key thorugh my java code... How can i do that?

Comment: @Abhi I think that the solution suggested by mikebz is the closest you can get to what you want. Be aware that to install your integration in production you have to pass a certification and I am sure that it won't be easy if you cannot demonstrate that your authentication mechanism is absolutely secure.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri -- whether authentication by the application is a good idea or not is mostly determined by the use case. If the application already knows who the user is, and if the app guards against forgery and repudiation by its users, then it is fine to use embedded signing. Be sure to clearly establish the chain of trust so you can later stand in court and be sure that the signer was who he said he was. Consult your legal dept about these issues and risks.

Comment: @LarryK this is exactly  my point. Unless your authentication and security is absolutely trustable, you'd better rely on DocuSign because if you don't the value of the signature depends only on your systems. So, in my opinion,  before using the embedded signature, think twice.