# Embedded in-session signing in docusing in my application

Tags: api, soap, docusignapi

How can I implement docusign in-session signing in my application? I am using java code for that.
I want to integrate docusign in-session signing in my application through docusign API?? Please tell me how i will call docusign API for that and which method used. 
Which web service i call for that.

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of your question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676590/i-want-to-add-the-docusign-api-with-my-web-application-software/34687168#34687168

Answer (score 2):

This is called 'Embedded Signing'. [Here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app) is an example written in Java from the DocuSign DevCenter website [recipes section](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/).

Comment: I've updated Mark's links to the newer version of the example software.

Comment: These links all just point back to https://developers.docusign.com/  :-(